# IAR Embedded Workbench IDE - ARM 8.40.2 error

Tags: embedded, iar, stm32f1

I am testing IAR in STM3210B-EVAL-OS-Probe-v5 mode. However, I am having a problem with the stm32f10x.h header file as follows. If you have this kind of experience, please help me how to solve it.

```
Error[Pe256]: invalid redeclaration of type name "s32" (declared at
    line 25 of "C:\Users\lsj\Desktop\2019
    3-2\임베디드\예제프로젝트\Micrium\Software\EvalBoards\ST\STM3210B-EVAL\IAR\OS-Probe\..\..\..\..\..\cpu\st\stm32\inc\
    C:\Users\lsj\Desktop\2019
    3-2\임베디드\예제프로젝트\Micrium\Software\EvalBoards\ST\STM3210B-EVAL\IAR\OS-Probe\stm32f10x.h
    487 stm32f10x_type.h") Warning[Pe301]: typedef name has already been
    declared (with same type) C:\Users\lsj\Desktop\2019
    3-2\임베디드\예제프로젝트\Micrium\Software\EvalBoards\ST\STM3210B-EVAL\IAR\OS-Probe\stm32f10x.h
```

-[image: stm32f10x.h]-------------------

stm32f10x.h

Comment: Are you sure that us the complete error log? It does not make a lot of sense - it looks like some of the lines have been truncated.  For example the line `declared at
    line 25 of "...` should end in a file name, but ends in a directory name.  Either way you should include the _code_ that causes this error - or at least the `#include ...` directives you are using.

Comment: Always start by googling the error message - that's the best way of finding others with the same problem, and often a solution too!  https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/tools/f/keil-forum/30572/type-redeclaration and https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/tools/f/keil-forum/27243/keil-and-error-256.  I suspect you are using components from different versions of the ST device headers.  What Include search paths do you have set - probably some redundant ones causing the wrong versions to be included.